# View with equal width and height

Tags: android, android-layout

what I want to do in a view is have a textview and to the right of it, have another custom view `X` with the same height as the textview and have width=height:

```
+---------------------+---+
|A flexible string    | X |
+---------------------+---+
```

My attempt so far is:

Inside the `X` class:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(height,height);
    Log.v("measure","width:"+height + " height:"+height);
}
```

and my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/mytext"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <mystuff.X
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mytext"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The log statement prints out:

```
width:1073741823 height:1073741823
width:37 height:37
width:1073741823 height:1073741823
width:37 height:37
width:1073741823 height:1073741823
width:37 height:37
```

when the view is created and it fills the width of the screen:

```
+---------------------+-----------------+
|A flexible string    |      X          |
+---------------------+-----------------+
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this.
Thanks!
Ian

Comment: did you change your question by adding parts of the answer from Sajid ? This is really confusing now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are treating the measure specs as actual pixels. They are in fact the ints that represent "fill_parent", "wrap_content", etc.

What you want to do is:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(height,height);
    Log.v("measure","width:"+height + " height:"+height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Your suggestion obviously helps but my view still doesn't look quite right. I have updated my question if you have any other pointers. Thanks.

Comment: Where are the other width/height prints with really large values coming from? Also, please set the params for mystuff.X to android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"     android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mytext"
 and nothing else.

Comment: still has the same problem. I'm not sure where the large numbers are coming from but the number is (MAX_INTEGER-1)/2

Comment: Well, since this method is emitting only ONE of those logs, I would have to guess (psychic debugging here, may be inexact) that you have another view that exists on that page and has width/height set to fill_parent. It might not be possible to tell them apart because it's easy to layer things with relative layouts. Try setting the mystuff.X's background to a distinct color in the xml to try and find it. Otherwise, this *should* work.

Comment: There is definitely only one of them, the only place 'X' is referenced is inside a listview (with one object). I will post if I find the solution.

Comment: Actually, that is a relevant data point. ListViews measure components very differently than normal layouts, so tricks may not work. One possible option is to use a linearlayout with horizontal layout to avoid the height expansion issue. Also, that explains the double-calls. One of them is the list doing layout, then the second is the object actually being measured and drawn. I guess this is why full code samples are critical to good answers...